# What introductory material is available linking complexity theory to cognitive science?

Tags: reference-request, cognitive-modeling, philosophy-of-mind, mathematical-psychology

- Does complexity theory speak to cognitive science?
- If yes, where can I find some material to explore that is suitable for undergraduate level understanding?
- In particular, is there any audio contennt on this?

Answer (score 8):

*In general, there are two types of 'complexity' that are studied. Usually, when people talk about 'complexity', especially on the internet, they mean Santa Fe Institute style complexity. This is a vague and poorly defined concept that has struggled for a number of years without making significant progress. It uses pretty words, but has yet to deliver on any real results. I will not discuss it more in this answer.*

The other type of complexity is [computational complexity theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) as studied by theoretical computer science. In general, this field is [too mathematical and too rigorous to engage with most of cognitive science and psychology](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/4807/29), but there are a few connections. I recommend looking at the cstheory question: [What is the complexity class most closely associated with what the human mind can accomplish quickly?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/5379/1037)

In that question, the author is curious to know which [complexity class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexity_class) most closely resembles what humans can achieve. My favourite [answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/5388/1037) discusses the **Tractable Cognition thesis**. For reference, see these papers:

- Iris van Rooij. [The Tractable Cognition thesis](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~szymanik/papers/TractableCognition.pdf). Cognitive Science, 32, pp. 939-984, 2008.
- Iris van Rooij. Parameters that make Cognitive Work Light. [FPT News: Parameterized Complexity Newsletter, June 2009](http://www.mrfellows.net/Newsletters/2009June_FPT_News.pdf).

A specialized part of computational complexity known as [computational learning theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_learning_theory) has been particularily notable in trying to make connections to cognitive science, in particular linguists. [Gold's theorem](http://www.lps.uci.edu/~johnsonk/Publications/Johnson.GoldsTheorem.pdf) on the non-learnability of certain families of formal languages was especially relevant in the early days of the [poverty of the stimulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poverty_of_the_stimulus) debate. You can learn more about it in these two questions:

- [Applications of computational learning theory in the cognitive sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/985/29)
- [General mathematical frameworks of language acquisition since Gold](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1066/33)

Keep in mind, that computational complexity is advanced material and requires a decent mathematical sophistication. However, with difficulty comes insights.